# Complexity of finding a common coprime element

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, computational-complexity, coprime

Let $n_1,\ldots,n_u$ denote $u$ positive integers, all of which are bounded above by some integer $N$.

> **Question: 
>   1. How hard is it to find an integer $m$ $(1 < m < N)$ that is coprime to $n_v$ for $1\leq v \leq u$?**

Comment: $m$ is not uniquely determined by those conditions, in general. It might also not exist for some inputs. Is there any other condition?

Comment: The integer $m$ need not be uniquely determined.  If the set of all such $m$ satisfying the coprimality criterion could be found, that would be even better.

Comment: If $N$ is small enough so that an array of $N$ bits can be used, simply sieve out the ineligible values.

Comment: The answer depends somewhat on the expected size of $N$. Is it $10$ digits? $100$ digits? $10000$ digits?

Comment: $N$ can be arbitrarily large. A complexity bound (as a function of $N$) would be great.